# How do I save the source code of a web site in c# using the ChromiumWebBrowser

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to make a program that will get the source code of a website using chromium-embedded web browser

```
chrome.ViewSource();
chrome.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml =>
{
    var html = taskHtml.Result;
});
```

this will not work because I am trying to put it in a textbox, not in notepad

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use `Chromium-embedded`? Is getting the source code the only reason you're using it? If so, either use a [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: No. Chromium embedded works with most websites where as web client uses internet explorer wich doesn't work with things like youtube and the NYC times.

Comment: but if I could find a way to have flash and java script in the default web browser I would use that.

Comment: "put it in a textbox, not in notepad"? Sounds like code in the post should be working... Or it is what you want to write? Please clarify what you are able to do already and what you have problem with. Also note that source code usually means response from web server and not rendered HTML.

Comment: When I use the code above the rendered HTML opens up in note pad on a separate program, not on my program. I want to save the HTML code as a variable. 
Thanks for your feed back.